# Complex differential equation that has all solutions complex

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

Consider the quadratic complex polynomial: $p(z)= az^2+bz+c$ for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ and the associated differential equation:

$$ \frac{dz}{dt}=p\left( z\left( t \right) \right),\qquad z\left( 0 \right)={{z}_{0}}\in \mathbb{C} $$

We are interested in the set of polynomials such that every solution of the differential equation for any $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$ lies in $\mathbb{C}$ for all time. Define this set of polynomials by $\mathcal{P}$. Write down necessary and sufficient conditions on $a, b, c$ so that $p \in \mathcal{P}$. If $p \in P$, what kind of zeros can $p$ have?

---

First of all I am not sure how to interpret this question. My first thought was that the imaginary part of the solution should never be zero (but I dislike this interpretation, $x=4$ is perfectly valid complex number). Anyway, I attempted to seperate the real and imaginary parts,

$$\begin{align}
  & \dot{x}=a{{x}^{2}}-a{{y}^{2}}+bx+c \\ 
 & \dot{y}=2axy+by \\ 
\end{align} $$

and further linearized it:

$$\left[ \begin{matrix}
   {\dot{\tilde{x}}}  \\
   {\dot{\tilde{y}}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right]=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   2a+b & -2a  \\
   2ay & b  \\
\end{matrix} \right]\left[ \begin{matrix}
   x  \\
   y  \\
\end{matrix} \right] $$

At this point I am stuck, what point should I linearize about? (there is still a $y$ in the matrix). I guess the condition we need is that $y \ne 0$ for all $t$ but I don't know how to put this in terms of $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w_1,w_2$ be the roots of $p$ so that the ODE is
$$
z'=a(z-w_1)(z-w_2).
$$
Then by partial fraction decomposition
$$
\frac{z'}{z-w_1}-\frac{z'}{z-w_2}=a(w_1-w_2)
$$
which integrates to
$$
\frac{z-w_1}{z-w_2}=K\exp(a(w_1-w_2)t)
$$
which should help to find the conditions that were asked for.